# Does there exist and impossible/invalid value for `Thread.getId()`?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any `long` value that cannot be returned by `Thread.getId()`? Having such a value would be very useful for indicating "no thread" or an unset value or whatever. I suppose I could just pick an ID at random and only have a 1 in 2^64 chance of this blowing up on me, but I'd rather not.

I could also create a thread that does nothing but hang around forever and use its ID as the invalid ID (since for all intents and purposes the thread does not exist except to provide an ID that I'm sure won't be used by another thread) - but that also seems like overkill.

Comment: Any negative number is "invalid".

Comment: ... and I'm one of those people who likes to say _read the javadoc!_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **Java Docs** Says ,

```
public long getId()
```

Returns the identifier of this Thread. The thread ID is a **positive long number** generated when this thread was created. The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime. When a thread is terminated, this thread ID may be reused.

So you can use any ***negeative number*** to fullfill your requirements

Answer (score 4):

One obvious option is to keep a `Long` instead of a `long` wherever you're using this. Then you can just use a null reference for "no associated thread". That's a good *general* approach to this problem.

However, in the specific case of threads, `[Thread.getId`][1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId--) makes it easy even if you need to use a `long`:

> Returns the identifier of this Thread. The thread ID is a **positive** long number generated when this thread was created. [...]

(Emphasis mine.)

So just use -1 (or any negative number) to indicate an invalid thread ID. While the "positive" here would suggest that 0 should be invalid too, I'd err on the side of caution and not rely on it - it's all too easy to write "positive" when one means "non-negative".

Comment: Well I look silly now. In the context I was using it, I needed to use this value in a `long[]` - which couldn't be changed to a Long[] without a lot of unfortunate boxing for the valid IDs (and ultimately I had to pass it to an API taking only `long[]`). Negative works fine though. There were two valid answers, so I gave the rep to @Neeraj since, well, the relative impact is a lot bigger. Good luck on your journey to 1,000,000.